# How to combine these queries into mongo db aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have 2 sql queries . These 2 queries results should be combined within one mongodb aggregation.

1st Query:

```
SELECT id,sum(DiscCount) as UTVCount from (SELECT  edu.dispositionBy as id ,count() as DiscCount. FROM `HRC_Education` edu WHERE edu.`RecommendedDisposition` = 'Edu.Disposition.UTV' AND edu.dispositionBy in "users" AND date(edu.DispositionDate) between "2022-01-12T00:00:00.0Z" AND "2022-01-23T00:00:00.0Z" group by id)
union
(SELECT emp.dispositionBy as id ,count() as DiscCount FROM `HRC_Employment` emp WHERE emp.`RecommendedDisposition` = 'Emp.Disposition.UTV' AND emp.dispositionBy in "users" AND date(emp.DispositionDate) between "2022-01-12T00:00:00.0Z" AND "2022-01-23T00:00:00.0Z" group by id)
```

2nd query:

```
 SELECT id,sum(DiscCount) as UTVCount from (SELECT  edu.dispositionBy as id ,count() as DiscCount. FROM `HRC_Education` edu WHERE edu.`RecommendedDisposition` = 'Edu.Disposition.UTV' AND date(edu.DispositionDate) between "2022-01-12T00:00:00.0Z" AND "2022-01-23T00:00:00.0Z" group by id)
    union
    (SELECT emp.dispositionBy as id ,count() as DiscCount FROM `HRC_Employment` emp WHERE emp.`RecommendedDisposition` = 'Emp.Disposition.UTV' AND date(emp.DispositionDate) between "2022-01-12T00:00:00.0Z" AND "2022-01-23T00:00:00.0Z" group by id)
```

My Mongo Query:

```
const result = HRC_Education
      .aggregate([
        {
          $match: {
            DispositionDate: { $gte: new Date("2022-01-12T00:00:00.0Z"), $lt: new Date("2022-01-23T00:00:00.0Z") },
            DispositionBy: { $eq: 'users' },
            RecommendedDisposition: { $eq: 'Edu.Disposition.UTV' }
          }
        },
        {
          $unionWith: {
            coll: "HRC_Employment",
            pipeline: [
              {
                $match: {
                  DispositionDate: { $gte: new Date("2022-01-12T00:00:00.0Z"), $lt: new Date("2022-01-23T00:00:00.0Z") },
                  DispositionBy: { $eq: 'users' },
                  RecommendedDisposition: { $eq: 'Emp.Disposition.UTV' }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: {
              id: "$DispositionBy"
            },
            total: { $sum: 1 }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id:0,
            id: "$_id.id",
            UTVCount: "$total"
          }
        }
      ])
```

Sample records for HRC_Education:

```
[{DispositionDate: 2022-01-14T00:00:00.0Z,DispositionBy:'users',RecommendedDisposition: 'Edu.Disposition.UTV' }]
```

Sample records for HRC_Employment:

```
 [{DispositionDate: 2022-01-14T00:00:00.0Z,DispositionBy:'users',RecommendedDisposition: 'Emp.Disposition.UTV' }]
```

With my mongo Query, I am able to convert either 1st query result or 2nd second result but not both. Can anyone please help me on this to combine these both sql queries into one mongo aggregation.

Comment: Welcome.    You seem very close.   What exactly do you mean by "converting" 1st or 2nd query but not both?   What output are you seeing that is not consistent with what you are expecting?

Comment: The two sql queries will execute based on if else condition in stored procedure. I am trying to do the same I am confused how to call these mongo aggregations based on if else conditions.

Comment: Oh -- so there's a stored procedure as well.  Please edit your post to show that if-then conditional logic.  The only diff between Q1 and Q2 is Q2 does not have the `DispositionBy = users` so we could either build the query conditionally (much easier in MQL than SQL) or get fancier if need be and use some `$cond` functions in a single query.